# undefined method `distance_of_time_in_words' for Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5.2.2 There are many empty(nil) fields in my DB and created a custom method to use `distance_of_time_in_words` in my model without errors.

```
  def my_distance_of_time_in_words
    if self.accounts.blank?
      "No Record Avaliable"
    else
      distance_of_time_in_words(self.accounts.first.updated_at,Time.now).titleize
    end
  end
```

And i am passing my object from view using :

```
<%= @customer.my_distance_of_time_in_words %>
```

It was working well and i restarted my PC and it says :

```
undefined method `distance_of_time_in_words' for #<Customer:0x00007f43b98601d8>
```

This is odd because as i said it was working as i expected.But it's not working now.

Comment: Did you `include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper` in your customer model?

Comment: @AbM I added it now and its working.Thanks.But how it worked before ?

Comment: it probably didn't. Maybe all the customer instances did not have an account. Also it is better to use a helper method here... I will add an answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The date helpers are not available in your model by default, so you need to explicitly include them.

```
class Customer < ApplicationRecord
  include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

  def my_distance_of_time_in_words
    if self.accounts.blank?
      "No Record Avaliable"
    else
      distance_of_time_in_words(self.accounts.first.updated_at,Time.now).titleize
    end
  end
end
```

However a better approach would be to use a helper method to accomplish what you need, this way you won't need to explicitly include `ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper` since it is already available to you there:

```
module CustomersHelper

  def my_distance_of_time_in_words(customer)
    if customer.accounts.blank?
      "No Record Avaliable"
    else
      distance_of_time_in_words(customer.accounts.first.updated_at,Time.now).titleize
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks in advices. I am pretty new on MVC and Rails. I will try helpers.